# Magento2 error when trying to add new integration from admin

Tags: xml, magento, exception, magento2

I have being working on a new magento website using magento 2.1.3 and I now need to add an extension but when I go to system->integrations and click "add new integration" I am given the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php on line 24

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: title in /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php on line 24
#0 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home/username/...', 24, Array)
#1 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Block/Adminhtml/Integration/Edit/Tab/Webapi.php(180): Magento\Integration\Helper\Data->mapResources(Array)
#2 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/view/adminhtml/templates/resourcetree.phtml(40): Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit\Tab\Webapi->getTree()
#3 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/username/...')
#4 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit\Tab\Webapi), '/home/username/...', Array)
#5 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/username/...')
#6 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#8 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(387): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#9 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml(57): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit\Tab\Webapi))
#10 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/username/...')
#11 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Integration\Edit\Tabs), '/home/username/...', Array)
#12 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/username/...')
#13 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#16 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('integration_edi...')
#17 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('integration_edi...')
#18 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('integration_edi...')
#19 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left')
#20 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#21 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left')
#22 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col')
#23 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#24 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col')
#25 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...')
#26 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#27 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...')
#28 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content')
#29 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#30 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content')
#31 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#32 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#33 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#34 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page')
#35 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#36 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page')
#37 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#38 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#39 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#40 /home/username/public_html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#41 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#42 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#43 /home/username/public_html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#44 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(221): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#45 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/NewAction.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\View->renderLayout()
#46 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction->execute()
#47 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#50 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Integra...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#51 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Integra...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#54 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /home/username/public_html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/NewAction/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#57 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#60 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#61 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 /home/username/public_html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#64 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#65 /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#66 /home/username/public_html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#67 {main}
```

I can't find any information on fixing this!

Answer (score 0):

Removing line 24 in /home/username/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php resolved my issue!